# Complete functions as a transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I have a delete process which deletes a file from the file system and deletes it's associated entry in a database. I'd like these two operations to pass/fail as an atomic unit. How can I accomplish this?

Here's the high level calls I'd like to wrap in a transaction of some kind.

```
var file = _fileRepository.Get(fileId);
deleteFileFromFileSystem(file.Name);
_fileRepository.Delete(file);
```

I tried using Entity Framework transactions but I can't rollback the file delete if the RDS delete fails.

Comment: The Windows file system (NTFS) does not have built-in transactional support. The easiest thing to do would probably be to save the files in a database table instead of on the file system. Then your EF transactions would work. Otherwise, you'll likely have to roll-your-own transaction system that includes the file system and database together (not a trivial task).

Comment: @Kevin: the Windows file system *does* have [built-in transactional support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa363764)! Unfortunately, this feature was so popular among developers (that is to say, not at all) that Microsoft didn't see the point of continuing to maintain it, and it's effectively already deprecated (though still present in current versions). Furthermore, actually using TxF in combination with a database transaction would be rather involved -- possible in theory, probably not worth it in practice.

Comment: The page documenting alternatives to TxF mentions [FILESTREAM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) storage as an alternative for these cases. This is, effectively, SQL Server wrapping around the file system to provide exactly these transactional guarantees, while still keeping separate files. Client access may become a little more involved, though.